# How to disallow certain user agents to access feeds in Feedburner?

Tags: rss, filtering, user-agent, feed, feedburner

I use Feedburner to deliver RSS feeds on my blog, and I prefer delivering them as E-mail subscriptions, but for past few days, I have been noticing that people are subscribing to my RSS feeds using other feed readers, such as mozilla built-in feed reader. I want to disable this, is there a way I can detect the user agent of "Mozzila compatible Agent"'s user-agent and input it somewhere in feedburner to disable the non-email subscriptions on feedburner?

Basically, I don't want anything except e-mail subscription in below screenshot-
[image: Feedburner Dashboard]

Comment: Why on earth would you want people to NOT get your content in the form they want?

Comment: Because, I want to keep track of my subscribers, I want to see who all are reading it, I can reach them using e-mail. But I can't reach them using other sources.

Comment: @PrateekSingle Firstly, you could easily just post something to that RSS feed if you want everyone to see it, instead of requiring that you email them. Secondly, this is off-topic for SO -- maybe it would be better for SuperUser or Server Fault.

Comment: Even if blocking in Feedburner based on user-agent was possible, the people subscribed to the feed by other means than by email could just subscribe directly to your Original Feed, possibly even faking their own user-agent as Feedburner.  If they didn't , and you blocked them from doing that, they could create a Feedburner feed from your Original Feed themselves, and subscribe to that in any means that want.